# Eclipse neon: different behavior for context menus ? Possible bug in eclipse v4.6.0?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-mars, eclipse-neon

[JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=directory)  is an eclipse-rcp v4.5.2 based application.
I tried to upgraded to eclipse v4.6.0 but found a problem with popups menu as follows:

- A part is defined in the e4 model as a `Part Descriptor` (PD). A popup menu is defined inside that PD
- On a certain action, the PD descriptor is instanciated and the part is added and displayed in a `Part Stack`. The body of this part is a `TabFolder` with multiple tabs corresponding to a JMS Q browsed. Each tab body is basically composed of a `TableViewer`/`Table` to display JMS messages.
- Each time a new tab is created, a new `TableViewer`/`Table` is created and the popupmenu is registered on the `Table` of the `TableViewer` with the following line of code:

  `menuService.registerContextMenu(table,<id of the popup menu in the part>);`

This works perfectly with eclipse v4.5.2 (Mars) but not with v4.6.0 (Neon) !

With neon, the popup is working only for the first tab: the context menu is visible and `@CanExecute` methods associated to the handlers/commands of the menu items are called . For subsequent tabs created, no popup is displayed and `@CanExecute` methods for the menu items are not called

If I register a different menu with a different Id (previously added to the PD) for each tab, it works! So I suspect this may be due to the fact that a menu with the same element id is added to multiple TableViever/Table even if it is coming from a different instance of a PD...

Is it a bug in neon? a regression? or do I benefit of a bug in mars that makes the application is working Ok with this version?

For now I have to downgrade (or not upgrade) to eclipse v4.5.2..

Comment: I think you will have to report this on Eclipse [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org) as only the developers can answer this. I can see the EMenuService code has changed but it is not clear why.

Comment: Done: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496695

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I pushed some code to correct the problem. It will be in eclipse v4.6.1+ [bug #496695](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496695)